# How to custom color the stroke in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, text, stroke, eyedropper

I am wanting the stroke of the text I'm creating to match the fill color of the text, to give it a 'bolder' look in Adobe Illustrator. 
I cannot seem to figure out how to eyedrop the custom color for the stroke, they way I have for the fill.

Comment: errr.... We kind of need to have an idea about software you are using to assist.

Comment: I am using Adobe Illustrator. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select the text using selection tool (<kbd>v</kbd>).
2. Double click the fill colour on left side tools panel.A popup will open.
3. Copy the colour code displayed after '#'.
4. Double click the stoke colour on left side tool panel (next to fill
   colour, looks life a frame).
5. Paste the copied colour code next to '#'.Click 'OK'.

Answer (score 5):

1. Select the text with the Direct Select tool (black arrow)
2. Open the Color window by selecting Menu->Window->Color or pressing F6
3. On the Color window, show the options if they are hidden by clicking on the top right corner and selecting Show Options. It should look like this:[image]
4. Click on the stroke thumbnail (see the next image). You will notice a small square set to the fill colour that appears under the thumbnails, with an arrow pointing up. Basically AI is suggesting you to set the stroke colour to the same colour of the fill.

[image]

5- Click on the small square (the suggested colour). The stroke is set to this colour.

[image]

P.S. Purists will frown at the fact that you are outlining a text to make it look bold. The "correct" solution would be to select a medium or bold version of the same font. Outlining a text can result in weird looking characters that don't look like the font was originally intended to look. But this was not part of your question, so ignore my comment : )